# Enable sign in with Gmail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

This code works fine, but I'm only able to send a mail through static mail `jhon.doe@gmail.com`. Is there a solution to enable login with Gmail so I can get the username and password to send the mail?

Here's my code:

```
public class EmailSender {
    private static final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

    public static boolean SendEmail(String to, String subject, String msg)
    {
        final String username = "jhon.doe@gmail.com";
        final String password = "abcd12345";
        boolean flag = false;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("jhon.doe@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);
            flag = true;
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

the Code of JSF page :

```
        <h:outputText value="Message" />
        <br></br>
            <p:inputTextarea rows="10" cols="50" completeMethod="#{inputTextareaView.completeArea}" value="#{faqbean.message}" queryDelay="750" minQueryLength="4" />
        <br></br>

        <p:commandButton action="#{faqbean.send()}" value="Send To Support" ajax="true"/>
```

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) in your code.  Then, explain what you're trying to do.  Where do you want to get the user name and password from?  Do you want some person to tell you what user name and password to use?  Do you want to get that information from a configuration file?  From a database?  Do you want to figure out what password to use based on the user name or email address?

Comment: @BillShannon Im adding a login with goole button so after logging in i want to send an email with that account

Comment: You probably want to learn about [OAuth2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2) so the user logging in can authorize your app to connect to their Gmail account.

Comment: I added the code of jsf page ...can i do this with OAuth2 ?

Comment: @BillShannon this was a really big help from you and i probably shoud add a token instead of password ?

Comment: OAuth2 is complicated, but if you follow the links you should find some examples that might help you figure out how to add it to your application.

Comment: @BillShannon can i configure java mail api so i can send an email using currently opened gmail account ?

Comment: What does "currently opened" mean?